# Create swift pod contains objc headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, xcconfig

I'm going to create a swift pod that contains code in non-module objc header, in my case is `<CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>`. So it doesn't pass the `pod lint` and said couldn't find the functions. And I tried this:

```
s.xcconfig = { "SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER" => "My-Bridging-Header.h" }
```

doesn't work too and warn:

```
error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported
```

Any experienced saver show me the way?

Comment: what exactly you trying to do can you explain more

Comment: @BhupatBheda I need use md5 string in my pod.

Comment: So you have created objective-c file with you and trying to call function from that objective-c file into your swift code ?

Comment: @BhupatBheda No, I didn't create any objc files. `<CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>` is a C header and not a framework or a lib, so I can't use `s.framework = xxx` or `s.libraries = xxx`.